# IOS app crashing without showing any errors in react native

Tags: android, react-native, pusher-js, pusherswift

My ios app is crashing without showing any errors.

I checked the **Last Exception Backtrace.** It showing like this:

```
    0   CoreFoundation                           0x18046589c __exceptionPreprocess + 160
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                          0x18005c09c objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   Foundation                               0x180cf3b90 -[NSMutableDictionary(NSMutableDictionary) classForCoder] + 0
    3   mobileAppName                            0x102eacd00 -[RCTEventEmitter sendEventWithName:body:] + 380
    4   mobileAppName                            0x103271eec PusherWebsocketReactNative.callback(name:body:) + 776
    5   mobileAppName                            0x103277ee8 closure #1 in PusherWebsocketReactNative.subscribe(_:resolve:reject:) + 688
    6   mobileAppName                            0x102c3ffa8 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed PusherPresenceChannelMember) -> () + 64
    7   mobileAppName                            0x102c1ac50 thunk for @escaping @callee_unowned @convention(block) (@unowned PusherPresenceChannelMember) -> () + 32
    8   mobileAppName                            0x102c41614 PusherPresenceChannel.addMember(memberJSON:) + 1996
    9   mobileAppName                            0x102c2ecd4 PusherConnection.handleMemberAddedEvent(event:) + 672
    10  mobileAppName                            0x102c303d0 PusherConnection.handleEvent(event:) + 564
    11  mobileAppName                            0x102c3657c closure #1 in PusherConnection.eventQueue(_:didReceiveEvent:forChannelName:) + 76
    12  mobileAppName                            0x102c05d00 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 48
    13  libdispatch.dylib                        0x1801424f4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    14  libdispatch.dylib                        0x180143d3c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    15  libdispatch.dylib                        0x180152b24 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 1272
    16  libdispatch.dylib                        0x18015261c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 40
    17  CoreFoundation                           0x1803c61b4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
```

I'm using Pusher authentication using presence channel.

Is that will be the issue? How should I fix this?